# React native Flatlist with modal handling for each item

Tags: react-native, modal-dialog, react-native-flatlist

... i have some data in json format which i want to render in Flatlist
For every item there is button pending .When user click on pending button a Modal is open with two button accept and reject.

...
I want when I click on reject button modal close and when click on accept button  then pending button convert in accepted

...
I try many times
But i was unable to change every item button in accepted

... It change only one item button  not every button as accepted

... Here is my code

...this is render function

```
    
const BookingData = [
  {
    id: '1',
    image:require('../../../assets/Ellipse4.png'),
    title: 'Sweets Pan Cakes',
    date: '29/05/2022 || 09:30',
    restaurant:require('../../../assets/Ellipse4.png'),
    review:  '5',
    bowl:require('../../../assets/hat.png'),
    listing:'Kalyan'
    },
    {
      id: '2',
      image:require('../../../assets/sneha.png'),
      title: 'Sweets Pan Cakes',
      date: '15/05/2022 || 09:30',
      restaurant:require('../../../assets/restaurant.png'),
      review:  '10',
      bowl:require('../../../assets/hat.png'),
      listing:'Kuldeep'
      },
];
```

````
....Flatlist code start here


```<FlatList
      data={BookingData}
      keyExtractor={item => 
     item.id}
     renderItem={()=>(
  
 
  <Modal
    transparent={true}
    visible={!active}
    onRequestClose={() => {
     console.warn("closed");
    }}>
    <View style={styles.containerModal}>
     

       <View style={{height:48, width:"40%"}}>
        <Pressable style={styles.nextbtn} onPress={() => setAccept(accept)}>
          <Text style={styles.nextbtntext}>Accept</Text>
        </Pressable>
      </View>

      <View style={{height:48, width:"40%"}}>
        <Pressable style={styles.rejectbtn} onPress={()=>{setactive(!active)}}>
          <Text style={styles.nextbtntext}>Reject</Text>
        </Pressable>
      </View>
       
  </Modal>

 ... <TouchableOpacity  onPress={()=>{setactive(!active)}}>
    { accept ?
    (
      <View style={styles.pendingBtn}>
      <Image source={require('../../../assets/pending.png')} style={{height:24,width:16}}/>
       <Text>Pending</Text>
      </View>
      )
      :
      (
        <View style={styles.aceptBtn}>
        <Image source={require('../../../assets/Ok.png')} style={{height:24,width:16}}/>
          <Text>Accepted</Text>
        </View>
        )}
      </TouchableOpacity>

  </View>
  </View>
````

)}```

Answer (score 0):

It's not exactly clear from your code but are you updating the `bookingData` accordingly when you click on `Accept`?

Comment: Booking data is data in json format
In simple word i have flat list with button pending .when I click on this open a modal with two options accept and reject.by clicking on reject button modal close  but when I click on accept button.flatlist pending button text or color should be changed.thats i want.